# domParser.Process throws Dom parser operation failed in lotus script

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript, domparser

I need to read xml file from local disk using lotus script.
I added the code in the script library and called from the notes view.

```
  origXML = "d:\dxl\xmldom.xml"
  outputFile = "d:\dxl\DOMtree.txt"

  On Error Goto errh

  Set session = New NotesSession    
  Set db = session.CurrentDatabase

  'create the output file
  Set outputStream =session.CreateStream
  outputStream.Open (outputFile)
  outputStream.Truncate

  Set inputStream = session.CreateStream
  inputStream.Open (origXML)

  'create DOM parser and process
  Set domParser=session.CreateDOMParser(inputStream, outputStream)
  domParser.Process
```

output and input stream , all are getting. But It throws the following error in domParser.Process

Dom parser operation failed

Please help me to solve this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `inputStream.open` return true? Does `d:\dxl\xmldom.xml` contain valid xml? What does `domParser.log` contain after the error?

Comment: The xml path was correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the xml header. It was

```
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
    xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
    xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" 
    xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
```

I removed all the attributes. I changed to `<xml>`, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error. See detail in `domParser.log`. Maybe incorrect encoding type or not found xsd|xslt stylesheet by url.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.  Instead of just removing the XML header attributes you can do something like the following.  [InputValidationOption property](http://notes.helsinki.fi/help/help8_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/f515ba63257774168525731b004a2632?OpenDocument)

```
'create DOM parser and process
Set domParser = session.CreateDOMParser(inputStream, outputStream)
domParser.InputValidationOption = VALIDATE_NEVER
domParser.Process
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Designer Help:

> Note In Release 7.0, this method was enhanced to handle a DTD located at a URL.  However, when using a URL, DOMParser.Process() will intermittently fail raising error #4602:"DOM parser operation failed" if the load on the server is too heavy, resulting in a time-out.  If this occurs, the calling application will need to try again.

So it is likely a problem with the dtd, either dtd server isn't responding or responding to slow. I had the same problem and solved it by just trying again if process failed. See code below:

```
Public Sub ParseString(s As String)
    On Error 4602 GoTo ParserOperationFailed

    Const MAX_RETRIES = 10

    Dim isProcessed As Boolean
    Dim numOfRetries As Integer

    Set domParser = session.Createdomparser(s)

    Do While numOfRetries < MAX_RETRIES And isProcessed = False
        Call domParser.Process()
        isProcessed = true
Retry:
    Loop

    If Not isProcessed Then
        Error 1000, "Unable to get dtd, DOM parser operation failed, tried " + CStr(numOfRetries+1) + "times"
    End If

    Set xmlDoc = domParser.Document

    Set Me.m_rootNode = xmlDoc.Documentelement

    Exit Sub
ParserOperationFailed:
    isProcessed = False
    numOfRetries = numOfRetries + 1
    Resume Retry
End Sub
```